# Using Maps in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Can anyone assist me in adding a Map to a Form in Codename One? I've been reading and searching, and can't find an "updated" demo/tutorial on using the library effectively.

IDE - IntelliJ
Build Tool - Maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old code works mostly the same as it did. The [github project instructions](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) are up to date and should work as expected. Just add the dependency and get the API keys from Google.

Then all you need to do is create a `BorderLayout` `Form` and place the map within it. E.g.:

```
Form mapForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
mapForm.add(CENTER, mapContainerInstance));
mapForm.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. I see how everything works now.